# How do I combine both outbound NAT and port forward for the same packet on same Linux?

Tags: linux-networking, nat

I want replace old ASA box by Linux. I nead combine both outbound NAT and port forward for the same packet - alias twice NAT (as described [here](https://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/nat/policy-nat-twice-nat/)).
I must change together in same packet:

- destination IP to 172.16.0.200:5252/udp and
- source IP with dependency on destination IP in source packet.

This translation I nead repeted for more combination of orig-destination -> translated-source/translated-destination.

 Example:

```
                       +---------------------------+
                       |                           |
 IoT clients           | eth0                 eth1 |                     IoT portal
 ORIGINAL PACKET       | 192.168.0.1    172.16.0.1 |      TRANSLATED PACKET
src:* dst:192.168.0.5+-> 192.168.0.5               |-->src:10.254.0.5 dst:172.16.0.200:5252/udp
src:* dst:192.168.0.6+-> 192.168.0.6               |-->src:10.254.0.6 dst:172.16.0.200:5252/udp
                       |                           |
                       +---------------------------+
```

I cannot change the IoT portal or IP address schema :( and I must replace 1:1.
I couldn't find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add two rule for every such translation: first rule is for port-forwarding (`DNAT`) and second rule to rewrite the source address (`SNAT`)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 --dst 192.168.0.5 -p udp --dport <N> -j DNAT --to 172.16.0.200:5252
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 --dst 192.168.0.6 -p udp --dport <N> -j DNAT --to 172.16.0.200:5252

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT --ctorigdst 192.168.0.5 -j SNAT --to 10.254.0.5
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT --ctorigdst 192.168.0.6 -j SNAT --to 10.254.0.6
```

Instead directly run of these commands use the iptables-save to write the full rule set into a file, then edit the file, and load the new rule set with the iptables-apply tool.

Comment: Thx very much. The --ctorigdst is paramater to join POSTROUTING to original destination IP which I cannot find